# Django 2.0 not reading POST request correctly (from Unity)

Tags: python, django, http, request

I'm receiving POST requests in a Django app using Python 3.5 (not from a web form, but from a Unity app). My goal is to send image data. I can confirm that Unity is generating the image correctly, and according to their docs I am sending it over correctly.

The POST request hits my local server, but Django `request.POST` and `request.FILES` are always empty no matter how I structure the request from Unity. However, if I read `request.body` into a `.txt` file, I can see what look like perfectly normal requests:

```
--pGBzDSypIQO4aFVbs4sjTmbBN5OpW3Huawm0D0ib
Content-Disposition: file; name="drawing"; filename="drawing.png"
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

‰PNG
IHDR  ð  ð   :R¼    IDATxìØÁ     0±¶ûïœÐ1”  
// etc...
```

Also tried other headers or sending dummy POST data. Even the simplest form-data fails to populate `request.POST`:

```
--hwlDqmtVKZ2EPkOJ7GuauDZNlYdE4nf4yNbGt9WR
Content-Disposition: form-data
Content-Type: text/plain; encoding=utf-8

a=b
```

Does this look improperly formatted to anyone else? No matter how I send stuff as far as I can tell, Django's `request.POST` does not populate. Any suggestions? Something look out of place in those requests? Know how a Django request *needs* to look in order to be readable? Would love to know, thanks!

Comment: Looks correct for me too. Could you try to send data to your server by using for example PostMan Chrome extension and check if the request.POST still doesn't populate?

Comment: What content type are you using for the overall request? It needs to be `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, both of you! `request.content_type` is `multipart/form-data` and `request.method` is `POST`. Then within the `request.body` I can set the image field content-type to type to either that or `image/png` but get the same results. I've sent some generic data w/ Postman and the app sees that just fine and turns it into a `QueryDict` as expected...

Comment: Also used Postman to send image files to the Django server and it serves it up into a QueryDict in request.POST and request.FILES as expected, but even the simplest Unity request stays tied up as raw byte[] data in their request.body object. It might have something to do with encoding sent from Unity? Still working.

Comment: Sorry to spam comments -- here's [an image of the Unity request](http://jamesckane.com/img/requestbin.PNG) from requestbin. See anything amiss?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is solved. I was using Python 3.5 and the Django test server, erroneously thinking TensorFlow only supported <= 3.5.x. When moving the app to a Heroku production server (to see if that would react differently), I had to bake a requirements.txt file and in doing so I figured out I could indeed use the latest Python version, 3.6.4. Switching to that version made the Django test server start receiving requests properly. I still need a whole mess of boundary generation string building code, but it actually works!